# How can I make pattern html5 with date from 1918 - 2004

Tags: html

I have that html5 pattern code:

```
(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])\.(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])|(?:30)\.(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]))|(?:31)\.(?:0[13578]|1[02]))\.(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}
```

This code is to date with format DD.MM.YYYY - it works good, but I would like limit it to dates bettwen 1918 - 2004 - How can I do it?

I tried to do it by myself, but really I can do it.

Comment: This is a Regex. You should ask for Regex.

Comment: And show an Html element you want to use the pattern. Because `<input />` allows you to add `min` and `max` properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:
`(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])\.(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])|(?:30)\.(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]))|(?:31)\.(?:0[1-8]|1[02]))\.(?:191[89]|19[2-9]\d|200[0-4])`

Comment: Oo, thank you for answer! :)
It's works fine from 1918, but I can put higher year than 2004... Could you check it for me?

Comment: You said to 2004. Untill what year you want? I checked it. It does not allow 2005, 2010... Copy the code again.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I had to copy wrong the code. Thank you for help!

Comment: Too long and can confuse newbie. Check to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use this tool http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/ 
Regex is `\b(191[89]|19[2-9][0-9]|200[0-4])\b`
Check the *Match Whole Word* checkbox 
Advice: in html tag you can specify the min and the max value for a certain input. Using regex is a little bit boring 
For your interest: https://github.com/erwinyusrizal/RegexNumericRangeGenerator this person made the tool behind the mechanism. You can check it and learn how it works

Comment: O, I never seen that things before - thank you! I will work on it!

Comment: I'm glad it works. If so you can mark it as the right answer